# Can't compile a Oracle db package with a SQL Macro and it caller in the same package

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, package, sql-macro

I'm getting this error, when try to compile a package with a sql_macro function and it caller in the same package.

ORA-62565: The SQL Macro method failed with error(s). ORA-04067: not executed, package body does not exist

If I delete the call, pkg can be compiled.
After compilation I can call the sql_macro function with the same statement from "outside" of the pkg.
Creating the same function as a seperate func and calling it in the pkg, also working.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PA_MACRO_TEST
AS
    FUNCTION FNC_CALL
        RETURN NUMBER;

    FUNCTION FNC_SQL_MACRO
        RETURN VARCHAR2 SQL_MACRO;
END PA_MACRO_TEST;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PA_MACRO_TEST
IS
   
    FUNCTION FNC_CALL
        RETURN NUMBER
    IS
       first_col VARCHAR2(50);
       sec_col NUMBER;
    BEGIN
   --SELECT 'test',1 into first_col,sec_col from dual;     
   SELECT * into first_col,sec_col FROM PA_MACRO_TEST.FNC_SQL_MACRO();
        RETURN 1;
    END FNC_CALL;

    FUNCTION FNC_SQL_MACRO
        RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS
       
    BEGIN

        RETURN q'[SELECT 'test', 1 from dual]';
    END FNC_SQL_MACRO;
END PA_MACRO_TEST;
/
```

Comment: No idea; consider posting code you use, it is difficult to debug code you can't see. Though, what about **package body does not exist**?

Comment: added a simple code example

Comment: This is mentioned [in this forum question](https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/can-t-compile-a-sql-macro-and-it-s-caller-in-the-same-packa-3897); the suggested explanation kind of makes sense but not sure it helps you - seems like you just can't do that.

Comment: @AlexPoole Thanks for your feedback. I alread found this post, but to be hornest I have no idea what it actually means. Is it technically not working or what do I have to change?

Comment: It looks like it cannot work - the macro would need to be defined in a different package to anything that tries to use it ([which works](https://dbfiddle.uk/EigOqBVU), as you already seem to know, but doesn't seem to be what you want).